# What is proper way to use local settings for celerybeat in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

Im using django 1.8.7, django-celery 3.1.17.
I want to override celery periodic tasks in local_settings, which i include at the end of basic settings file.

This code in local settings file doesnt work:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://test:test@localhost/'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "test_task": {
        "task": "test.ptask",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/5"),
        "options": {'queue': 'slow_tasks'}
    }
}
```

Comment: How your run the celery workers? using `manage.py` or `celeryd`?

Comment: celery -A test worker -l warn -Q slow_tasks --concurrency=10
from proj root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call celery directly it will not obey the django `settings.py`. Instead call with

```
manage.py celery -A test worker -l warn -Q slow_tasks --concurrency=10
```

Please note you should add django-celery to your INSTALLED_APP.

Also please check this page: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-initd-celerybeat-django-example

Comment: Old alias to the "celery worker" command.
manage.py: error: no such option: -A


`manage.py celery -A test worker -l warn -Q slow_tasks --concurrency=10` works for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem was also in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler".
Periodic tasks are stored in DB, so u just need to delete them from admin panel.